# How to set size of child TextBoxes in a GridView of Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, android-gridview

I have a GridView in my Android Application. I have noticed it that no matter how I specify the height/width of the individual TextFields they are never reflected in the GridView's TextFields.

Finding an alternative now I'm using `$android:columnWidth="90dp"` to create the TextViews of specific width. **But, how do I set the hight of the TextViews inside the GridView?**

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/park_cont"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".ParkingView"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_parking_view" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to override the `getView()` of the `ArrayAdapter` and set the height for the `LayoutParam` of the `View`. You'll need to do something along the following lines,

```
val adapter = object : ArrayAdapter<String>(
        mContext,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, flowers
) {
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val tvCell = super.getView(position, convertView, parent)

        //Set the height of the view by settings it's layoutParams.height
        tvCell.layoutParams.height = 1100

        // Return the modified item
        return tvCell
    }
}

mGridView.adapter = adapter
```